# How to repeat the condition until the new value is seen or reached?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula for getting the value from another sheet if the specific cell on it has the value of **"x"**.

```
=IF(SheetName!CellToCompare="x",SheetName!CellValue)
```

The problem is if the column doesn't have a value of **"x"** it will return the value of **"False"**.

What I want is something like a loop where it will check if the value of **"x"** exists, if not then ignore the **"false"** return and continue to the next cell until it gets another **"x"**.

Here's the example of the sheet where I want to get the value.
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0izq.png)

With the formula of `=IF(Sheet1!B2="x",Sheet1!A2)`, the result will be; [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3VYh.png)

What I want is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xtyi.png).

Anyone can help me?

EDIT: I have Office Pro Plus 2019

Comment: Why do you want to see `FALSE` in your desired output? Also, what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV - I don't want to see `FALSE` output. I'd like the formula to skip the false and only fill trues, meaning that when I auto-filled the cell I would have a nice column full of string value from sheet1. `If NOT then IGNORE the FALSE`, Please read the question.

Comment: is Macros or VBA allowed? That will be easy.

Comment: @Polar - No, I can actually do it with Macros but I'd like to skip it, otherwise, I will just filter it.

Comment: Aww, I see. Yep, looks like filter is your best option.

Comment: There was a function called `INDIRECT` in excel, it might help you. Something like `=IF(Sheet1!B2="x", Sheet1!A2, IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B" & ROW() + 1)="x", INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW() + 1)))`, it will jump into the next cell if "x" from the current cell your looking is not found. its still not perfect but you can try it.

Comment: @Polar - Prety close, but still not what I want. Your formula actually works but only for the next one. I still get `FALSE` and having a duplicate result. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$50,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$1:B$50="x",ROW(Sheet1!B$1:B$50)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROW()-1)),"")`
If in cell `A1` you have `Value 1` in the sheet you want to get your list, in `A2` enter this array formula with `ctrl + shift + enter` and drag down / to the right.
I used row 1 to 50 for this, but change that to the actual range.

The formula checks for the row number which has an `x` and returns these from small to large for the indeed of the row containing the strings.

Comment: Nope, it will have a blank cell instead. It should continue looking for "x" in the next cell from the `sheet1`, if it found a new one then fill the cell.

Comment: I misunderstood it in the first place. I edited my answer, which should list only the strings marked `x` for your value.